# Spring/Hibernate - Table per class Inheritance with AttributeOverrides overwriting column mapping in subclasses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

**NOTE**: classes and packages were renamed due to not being able to share the actual code

In a system there was already the following classes:

```
@Entity
class SomeEvent {
    @Column(name="creation_date")
    private Instant creationDate;   
    // Other attributes ommitted for clarity
}

@Entity
class AnotherEvent {
    @Column(name="event_date")
    private Instant eventDate;  
    // Other attributes ommitted for clarity
}
```

Since they shared a common ancestry, I did the following inheritance that would also allow me to query both entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class BaseEvent {
    private Instant creation;
    // Other attributes ommitted for clarity
}

@Repository
interface BaseEventRepository extends JpaRepository<BaseEvent, Long> {
    List<BaseEvent> findAllOrderByCreationDesc();
}

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="creation", column=@Column("creation_date"))
class SomeEvent extends BaseEvent {
    // Other attributes ommitted for clarity
}

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="creation", column=@Column("event_date"))
class AnotherEvent {
    // Other attributes ommitted for clarity
}
```

When running the application I get the error: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity annotated with @Inheritance cannot use @AttributeOverride or @AttributeOverrides: `com.mypackage.SomeEvent`.

Since I can't change the current tables I was hoping to have some way I could map the entities with the creation date fields being overitten in the subclasses, while being able query them by Creation Date through a superclass.

Versions

- Java 1
- Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@AttributeOverride not working with Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772880/attributeoverride-not-working-with-inheritance)

Comment: @Smutje no, unfortunatelly it doesn't. If I use a Mapped Supeclass I won't be able to query by it.

Comment: Supporting polymorphism is not required by JPA for table_per_class. So it is not portable.